# multiplexing/demultiplexing different messages types in a protobuf stream

Tags: protocol-buffers

I would like to send a stream of different protobuf messages through the wires and be able to differentiate them at arrival as they are coming.

Let's say I have a *.proto like that:

```
message Book {
//...
}
message BlueRay{
//...
}
```

And then and the sender side, I serialize let's say this sequence (pseudo code in C#):

```
Book1.WriteDelimitedTo(myStream);
BlueRay1.WriteDelimitedTo(myStream);
Book2.WriteDelimitedTo(myStream);
```

How can I do to know the order/types of messages I'm getting on the receiver side? (The contract is available on both sender and receiver side of course)
Depending of my sender's state I can not presume/tell what is going to be sent and in which order...

I understood that there is no built-in way to do that like stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming), but for instance for the size of the message there was a helper (C# API helper WriteDelimited method to embedd size).

How can I do to get/map the type of a received message?

My server will be written in a given language (C# actually), but my clients should be "implementable" in any protobuf supported target, so I don not want to set up something that would serialize C#/CLR specific stuff in between...

I'm maybe using protobuf in a weird way? I'm trying to set up a kind of protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found out how to do that (only in C# at the moment).

Basically, I'm writing the following to the stream:

- the coming message descriptor's target name (in proto file, as both end share this definition), using the primitive for string serilization
- the coming message size, using the primitive for size serialization
- the serialized message into the stream

This results in a method like the following:

```
public static void WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, IMessage message)
{
    MessageDescriptor stateMsgDescriptor = message.Descriptor;

    using (CodedOutputStream codedOutStr = new CodedOutputStream(outputStream, true))
    {
        codedOutStr.WriteString(stateMsgDescriptor.FullName);

        int size = message.CalculateSize();
        codedOutStr.WriteLength(size);

        message.WriteTo(codedOutStr);

        codedOutStr.Flush();
    }
}
```

As [stated here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming),

> The Protocol Buffer wire format is not self-delimiting, so protocol
>   buffer parsers cannot determine where a message ends on their own